# How do I run xrandr?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, xorg, xrandr

I'm running xubuntu and I'm trying to run `xrandr` but I get the error `RandR extension is missing`. I know that it is installed because I ran `sudo aptitude install x11-xserver-utils`. I just uninstalled the latest nvidia drivers. I read that Nvidia might interfere with xrandr over xinerama?

Is xrandr disabled? If so, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 from nvidia-352 and then restarting fixed the issue.